# Why does my IP address start with '192.'?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I am from a non-networking background. I suddenly wondered why the companies I worked in almost always had the IP addresses like `192.168.x.x`. Why can't they have something like `1.2.3.4`?

I understand that an IP address has a <networkSection> and <HostSection>, and there is a concept called subnetting.

Also, 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255 seem to be used for private use.

How does the IP address matter thought all devices are connected to the Internet through a router?

Comment: you can go through this link http://trendblog.net/ever-wondered-use-192-168-x-x-ip-addresses-home/

Answer (score 19):

According to [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918), addresses in the `192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255` range are *private*. Such addresses can be used internally by any network so they're often used **inside** an organization. They cannot be used on the Internet since they aren't intended to be kept globally unique.

`192.168.X.X` isn't the only private range defined in the RFC. You might also run into `10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255` or `172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255`

Most other addresses are public, and have to be assigned to the network by a [Regional Internet Registrty (RIR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Malt. I glanced over RFC1918, and realized below statement: The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
   following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

     10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix).   Shall i consider apart from these ranges can not be assigned to private? for example : 9.x.x.x ?

Comment: Addresses outside these ranges are not private, but might be reserved for other reasons.Wikipedia has a nice list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Subnet Calculator Explanation:

> First depict the ip address in binary.
> Take for example 10.0.0.0 and convert to binary:
>
> ip address: `00001010.00000000.00000000.00000000`
>
> First we determine what class of address it is:
>
> - If the first bit is 0 it is a Class A address
> - If the first two bits are 10 it is a Class B address
> - If the first three bits are 110 it is a Class C address
> - If the first four bits are 1110 it is a Class D multicast address
> - If the first four bits are 1111 it is a Class E experimental address

You might see a kind of playing around with symmetries and numbers of 1-Bits (**in brackets**: number of 1-Bits for each [nibble](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) of the subnet mask prefix, just *my guess* what might have been thought of, since these Bit patterns were “sacrificed” for private networks):

- class A: 00001010 **(#1/nibble: 02)**: 10/8
- class B: 10101001.11111110 **(#1/nibble: 2243)**: 169.254/16 (automatic IPs)
- class C: 11001100.0001 **(#1/nibble: 221)**: 172.16/12
- class C: 11000000.10101000 **(#1/nibble: 2021)**: 192.168/16

Network Calculators:

- [CIDR / VLSM Supernet Calculator](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php)
  and for classful subnets, use the [IP Subnet Calculator](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/)
- [Network Calculators](http://www.subnetmask.info/)
- [IP Calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc)

Further links:

- [What Is an IP Address?](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/what-is-an-ip-address.htm)
- [IPv4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4)
- [CIDR - Classless Inter Domain Routing](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing): Mind that CIDR does not have classes, therefore: "classless".